# Why Can't Cubic Equation Have Fractional Solutions When Its Coefficients Are All Integers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, cubics

In Leonhard Euler's book, "The Elements of Algebra" he seems to say that if we convert any cubic equation into the form $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$, and make sure that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are integer numbers, then if the equation has any rational solutions, then they can only be integer solutions. In the book:

> When we have removed fractions from an equation
> of the third degree, according to the manner which has been explained, and none of the divisors of the last term are found to be a root of the equation, it is a certain proof, not only that the equation has no root in integer numbers, but also that a fractional root cannot exist; which may be proved as follows. Let there be given the equation $x^3 - ax^2 + b - c = 0$, in which, $a$, $b$, $c$ express integer numbers. If we suppose, for example, $x = \frac{3}{2}$, we shall have $$\frac{27}{8} - \frac{9}{4}a + \frac{3}{2}b - c = 0.$$ Now here, the first term alone has $8$ for the denominator; the others being either integer numbers, or numbers divided by $4$, or by $2$, and therefore cannot make $0$ with the first term. The same thing happens with every other fraction.

I don't really understand the argument he's trying to present. I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: yes, it is the rational roots theorem. If all coefficients are integers AND  the highest degree coefficient is $1$  then any rational root is an integer

Comment: Rational root theorem proof here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: without rational root theorem, just for this example, multiply the displayed equation by $4$ and move all but the first term to the right side, and get $\frac{27}{2}=9a-6b+4c,$which since $a,b,c$ are integers is saying that $\frac{27}{2}$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a polynomial $c_nx^n  + c_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + c_1x+c_0$ with integral coefficients $c_i$ and a rational root $r$.  Write the rational root in *reduced* form, say $r = a/b$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers that are relatively prime.

Claim: $b$ is a factor of $c_n$ and $a$ is a factor of $c_0$. In particular, if $c_n = 1$ then $b = \pm 1$, so $r = a/b = \pm a$ is an integer.

Proof of claim: setting $x = r = a/b$ in the polynomial,
$$
0 = c_nx\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n  + c_{n-1}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{n-1} + \cdots + c_1\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)+c_0 
$$
and now multiply through by $b^n$ to clear the denominator:
$$
0 = c_na^n  + c_{n-1}a^{n-1}b + \cdots + c_1ab^{n-1} +c_0b^n.
$$
This equation has no denominators anywhere: each term is an integer.

Every term except maybe $c_na^n$ has a factor of $b$, and the left side is $0$, so the term $c_na^n$ has a factor of $b$. Since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, the only way $b$ can be a factor of $c_na^n$ is to have $b$ be a factor of $c_n$.

Every term except maybe $c_0b^n$ has a factor of $a$, and the left side is $0$, so the term $c_0b^n$ has a factor of $a$. Since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, the only way $a$ can be a factor of $c_0b^n$ is to have $a$ be a factor of $c_0$.